# Oracle SQl: Use column value as column name, not using dynamic sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below requirement,

The values from the column "sname" from table1 should be used to fetch the data from the column from table 2, which has the same name.

For ex, table1 has 'Segment1' as value, i need to use this in such a way that, i get the data from the 'Segment1' column from the table2.
[I have the sid and appId values]

```
select * from table1;
sid         sname
------------------------------
1           Segment1    
1           Segment2



select * from table2;
appId       Segment1        Segment2 
---------------------------------
a1          fld1            fld2
a2          cmp1            cmp2
```

In table2, 'a1' is the old row, a2 is the new row. All this information I can get from a CLOB.

So I want the data to be displayed like this

```
segment   oldvalue  newvalue
----------------------------
segment1   fld1 cmp1
segment2   fld2 cmp2
```

I would want to have this not using the dynamic SQL. Thanks in advance.

If dynamic SQL is must for solving this issue, could you please share the solution.

> Note: The number of segments (as data) in table1 and the number of
>   'Segment' columns in table2 may differ.

Comment: This is not possible without dynamic SQL. However, "Dynamic SQL" simply means: build your SQL string ad hoc. Select the names from table1, loop through the result and build your query to select from table2. You can use PL/SQL or any other programming language (Java, PHP, whatever) to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot dynamically name columns.  For the specific problem you describe, you can do what you want as:

```
select segment, max(oldvalue) as oldvalue, max(newvalue) as newvalue
from ((select 'segment1' as segment, segment1 as oldvalue, null as newvalue
       from table2
       where appid = 'a1'
      ) union all
      (select 'segment1' as segment, NULL as oldvalue, segment1 as newvalue
       from table2
       where appid = 'a2'
      ) union all
      (select 'segment2' as segment, segment2 as oldvalue, null as newvalue
       from table2
       where appid = 'a1'
      ) union all
      (select 'segment2' as segment, NULL as oldvalue, segment2 as newvalue
       from table2
       where appid = 'a2'
      )
     ) t
group by segment;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,This is still hardcoding the column names. If dynamic SQL is must, could you please provide a solution for this requirement.

Comment: @SushmaNooka Yes, "not dynamic" meas "hard coded" - that's what you have asked for.